# Google Cloud SQL (second generation) - Too many connections despite connection pooling?

Tags: java, mysql, google-app-engine, jpa, google-cloud-sql

I have a lot of open connections to my Cloud SQL database and I am wondering why. I have a couple of JPA applications (runnding on app engine as well) connected to it doing some basic stuff, but not executing that much queries.

SHOW PROCESSLIST shows me there are currently 1727 connections and the number is slowly increasing. Most of them seem to be sleeping. The oldest ones around 7 hours.

[image]

I configured c3p0 connection pooling in my persistence.xml, but it seems, the old connections are not reused.

This is my persistence.xml:

```
    <persistence-unit name="de.gwtprime.jpa">


        <properties>

            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver"
                value="com.mysql.jdbc.GoogleDriver" />

            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url"
                value="jdbc:google:mysql://myapp:us-central1:myproject/mydb" />

            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />

             <!-- user and password only needed for second generation? -->
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="user" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="pw" />

            <property name="hibernate.use_sql_comments" value="true" />


            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />

            <!-- Set this to 0 otherwise you sometimes get errors -->
            <property name="hibernate.connection.pool_size" value="5" />


            <!-- Cache -->
            <property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider" />
            <property name="hibernate.cache.use_structured_entries" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="true" />

             <!-- Configuring Connection Pool -->
              <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size" value="5" />
              <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size" value="15" />
              <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout" value="300" />
              <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements" value="50" />
              <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period" value="150" />

        </properties>

    </persistence-unit>
```

Whats the best way to fix/improve the situation or investigate it?

Comment: How many App Engine instances do you have running? Keep in mind every App Engine instance is its own "copy" of the application with its own connection pool.

Comment: I have 30 instances running. That means with a max size of 15 connections there should be max 30 instances * 15 connections -> 450 connections right?

Comment: Also the instances do use the task queue. Does every task in the task queue have it's own pool as well? That could be an explanation...

Comment: That sounds right. Unfortunately it's hard to know where the connections are coming from without knowing more about your application. Are most of these connections have the cloudsqlproxy~ hostname? Are they coming from the same subnet range? First step would be to establish if most of them are coming from App Engine and then narrowing things down from there.

Comment: My app engine understanding is limited but I believe task queues end up invoking HTTP requests that spin up app engine instances so those should be reflected in your App Engine instance counts.

Comment: Make sure you are looking at instance counts for all active services/versions.

Comment: Yes all of them are coming from "cloudsqlproxy~". I just recently switched from first generation to the second generation of cloud sql and at first generation they all were localhosts and I could restrict the sql user to localhost connections... was wondering about that as well.